# How can I get the correct average and grade?

Tags: java

This is my code right now:

```
package lessons4;
public class prog2 {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int row , col, total=0;
        int average;
        int[][] y = {{85,83,77,91,76},
                    {80,90,95,93,48},
                    {78,81,11,90,73},
                    {92,83,30,69,87},
                    {23,45,96,38,59},
                    {60,85,45,39,67},
                    {77,31,52,74,83},
                    {93,94,89,77,97},
                    {79,85,28,93,82},
                    {85,72,49,75,63}
                    };

        String[] names = {"Johnson" , "Aniston" ,"Cooper", "Gupta", "Blair", "Clark", "Kennedy", "Bronson", "Sunny", "Smith"};

        System.out.println("Name \tS1 \tS2 \tS3 \tS4 \tS5 \taverage \tgrade ");
        for(row=0; row<=9; row++)
        {
            System.out.print(names[row] + "\t");
            for(col=0; col<=4; col++)
            {
                System.out.print(y[row][col] + "\t");
                total = total + y[row][col];
            }
            average = total/5;
            System.out.println(+average);
        }
    } 
}
```

Here is my current output:

```
Name    S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  average     grade 
Johnson 85  83  77  91  76  82
Aniston 80  90  95  93  48  163
Cooper  78  81  11  90  73  230
Gupta   92  83  30  69  87  302
Blair   23  45  96  38  59  354
Clark   60  85  45  39  67  413
Kennedy 77  31  52  74  83  477
Bronson 93  94  89  77  97  567
Sunny   79  85  28  93  82  640
Smith   85  72  49  75  63  709
```

As you can see, the average value outputted does not seem to be correct.

Secondly, how would I go about assigning a grade for each student, because I am really confused about how I could do that.

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try again.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Please read [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And there is a syntax error here `System.out.println(+average);`. What is expected from `+average` ?

Comment: You're missing `total = 0` before the inner loop. --- If you had followed good programming style and declared the local variables where they were needed, instead of all up front, this problem wouldn't have happened. `for (int row=0; row<=9; row++) { int total = 0; ...` and `for (int col=0; col<=4; col++) ...` and `int average = total/5;`

Comment: @RomeoSierra While the `+` doesn't make sense it will not throw a syntax error.

Comment: @shash678 Yeah sorry I missed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your on the right track all you need to do really is change the type of the variables `total` and `average` from **int** to something **double**, so the average is not rounded to the nearest integer and reset `total` to `0` for every student, so the `total` and therefore `average` value calculated is specific to each student.

As for assigning a letter grade you could use a method like `getGrade` below (modify as required):

```
class Prog2 {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int row, col = 0;
    double average, total = 0;
    int[][] y = {{85,83,77,91,76},
                {80,90,95,93,48},
                {78,81,11,90,73},
                {92,83,30,69,87},
                {23,45,96,38,59},
                {60,85,45,39,67},
                {77,31,52,74,83},
                {93,94,89,77,97},
                {79,85,28,93,82},
                {85,72,49,75,63}
                };

    String[] names = {"Johnson" , "Aniston" ,"Cooper", "Gupta", "Blair", "Clark", "Kennedy", "Bronson", "Sunny", "Smith"};

    System.out.println("Name \t\tS1 \tS2 \tS3 \tS4 \tS5 \tAverage \tGrade ");
    for(row=0; row<=9; row++) {
      System.out.print(names[row] + "\t\t");
      total = 0;
      for(col=0; col<=4; col++) {
        System.out.print(y[row][col] + "\t");
        total = total + y[row][col];
      }
      average = total/5;
      System.out.println(average + "\t\t" + getGrade(average));
    }
  }

  public static String getGrade(double average) {
    if(average > 97) {
      return "A+";
    } else if (average > 93) {
      return "A";
    } else if (average > 90) {
      return "A-";
    } else if (average > 87) {
      return "B+";
    } else if (average > 83) {
      return "B";
    } else if (average > 80) {
      return "B-";
    } else if (average > 77) {
      return "C+";
    } else if (average > 73) {
      return "C";
    } else if (average > 70) {
      return "C-";
    } else if (average > 67) {
      return "D+";
    } else if (average > 63) {
      return "D";
    } else if (average > 60) {
      return "D-";
    } else {
      return "F";
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Name        S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  Average     Grade 
Johnson     85  83  77  91  76  82.4        B-
Aniston     80  90  95  93  48  81.2        B-
Cooper      78  81  11  90  73  66.6        D
Gupta       92  83  30  69  87  72.2        C-
Blair       23  45  96  38  59  52.2        F
Clark       60  85  45  39  67  59.2        F
Kennedy     77  31  52  74  83  63.4        D
Bronson     93  94  89  77  97  90.0        B+
Sunny       79  85  28  93  82  73.4        C
Smith       85  72  49  75  63  68.8        D+
```

Comment: public static String getGrade(double average) {
    if(average >=85 && <=100) {
      return "A";
    } else if (average >=75 && <=84) {
      return "B";
    } else if (average >=65 && <=74) {
      return "C";
    } else if (average >=50 && <=64) {
      return "D";
    } else if (average < 50) {
      return "F";
  }
}

Comment: how do i get rid of the syntax error for a grading like this?

Comment: Add `average` after the `&&` in each if statement. Not the code you posted above will not return any grade if the average is something like `84.5` for instance? Can you see why? Try something like the new `getGrade` method in the answer. Also read my explanation for why the `&&` parts are redundant, anyway.

Comment: @a8rt Could you please click my answer as correct? I would really appreciate it? I am on the grind for 5000 points, ty.

Comment: How do i make it too non decimal point because my homework requires that type of grading.

Comment: You cannot calculate an average without decimal point? think about if a total is an odd number and you divide by an even number then the average will contain a decimal point...

Comment: @a8rt I will write one more peice of code for you if you mark my answer is correct, until then I won't write any code for you.

Comment: i cannot mark your answer correct because i am below 15 reps

Comment: @a8rt ask another question with your new problem

Comment: Well i cannot do that because i have to wait for 3 days!

Comment: @a8rt There you go, I made your code work as you wanted: https://repl.it/repls/SophisticatedAlertLanservers it is **far from optimal** but I think it is what you want.

Comment: im sorry but the link you provided does not have anything

Comment: is it possible if you type it here because i really need it urgently !

Comment: @a8rt Try this link: https://repl.it/repls/SophisticatedAlertLanservers I confirmed it works... Also remember, it is not my fault if you don't get 100% I warned you about the need to use a datatype that allowed decimals.